# Incorrect DVD rip timing

Tags: ubuntu, video, vlc-media-player, dvd, handbrake

[image]

The problem using handbrake on Ubuntu. VLC playing the DVD is shown on the left, the same player playing the rip is shown on the right. The rip is "faster" than the DVD.

I am trying to create a DVD rip with exactly the same timing as the DVD. I am using hand brake and this has always worked for me so far. But in the case shown above the rip is faster and I do not understand why. I already tried to force a constant frame-rate using handbrake and got the exact same result.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Wrong framerate for whatever reason. Handbrake uses a bunch of other programs, and probably misses different/varying framerates because of that.